# Rails db:seed error "undefined method `finder_needs_type_condition?' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, sqlite, seeding

I have a problem when attempting to populate my sqlite db. There's not much info regarding the specific error "finder_needs_type_condition?" that I can find, but I don't have much experience with Rails yet to even suspect where the problem could be.

Model:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :name, :class, presence: true
end
```

Controller:

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  @user_id = current_user[:id]

  def index
    @characters = Character.all
  end

  def show
    @character = Character.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @character = Character.new
  end

  def create
    @characters = Character.all
    @character = Character.create(character_params)
  end

  private
    def character_params
      params.require(:character).permit(:user_id, :name, :class)
    end
end
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "class"
  t.integer  "user_id",    default: 0, null: false
end
```

seeds.rb:

```
Character.delete_all
Character.create!([
  {id: 1, name: "nameone", class: "Warrior", user_id: 1},
  {id: 2, name: "nametwo", class: "Mage", user_id: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "namethree", class: "Wizard", user_id: 1},
  {id: 4, name: "namefour", class: "Warlock", user_id: 1},
  {id: 5, name: "namefive", class: "Rogue", user_id: 1}
])
```

And the error when attempting seed:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `finder_needs_type_condition?' for nil:NilClass
/var/rubyapps/test/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Have I misunderstood something when generating the model?

Comment: It's scary how similar this is to my problem, here's one of my test cases that are giving me errors :D
`let(:character1) { Character.create(user: user, name: "characterName", class: "Wizard") }}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot have a column name of `class`, because this is a reserved word.  You're already using `character_class` in your seeds, which doesn't exist in the the database, so all you need to do is rename this column the database.

```
rails g migration RenameCharactersClassColumn
```

Then add this line to the migration file.

```
rename_column :characters, :class, :character_class
```

Run `rake db:migrate` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error when I created a new rails database and tried to create a new entry via the front-end.

I had a column named 'class'. As it was a new database, it had no information so I simply deleted it and recreated it, but calling the column 'class' something different. Works fine, no more error message.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `character_class` with `class` in your seeds.rb as you have column name `class` in characters table.

```
{id: 1, name: "nameone", class: "Warrior", user_id: 1},
```