# When trying to create a new application record, returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In `UserController` I need create a new `Character`. However, when using the `Character.new` returns `nil`. How to solve this problem?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /users
  def create
    character = Character.new # error where
    character.xp = 0
    character.save

    ...

    render json: "success"
  end

end
```

Character's model is empty.

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord

end
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @Pavan `NoMethodError (undefined method `finder_needs_type_condition?' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'`

Comment: what all columns do you have in character model?

Comment: @kiddorails I have "xp" and "class" columns

Comment: @Macabeus: Added answer below :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails db:seed error "undefined method \`finder\_needs\_type\_condition?' for nil:NilClass"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761577/rails-dbseed-error-undefined-method-finder-needs-type-condition-for-nilnil)

Comment: @kiddorails Thank you. I spent an hour with this stupid error =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `class` column in any of your model since it is a reserved keyword. You should make a migration and rename this column to something else.

Reference: [Rails db:seed error "undefined method `finder_needs_type_condition?' for nil:NilClass"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761577/rails-dbseed-error-undefined-method-finder-needs-type-condition-for-nilnil)